# local DB error 50

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

when i want to run my program in other PC i have this error:

> *See the end of this message for details on invoking 
>   just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at WindowsFormsApplication7.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:-1983577849,State:0,Class:20*
```

these are my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Drug
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }           

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath+@"\ABC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
            conn.Open();
            fillgrid();
        }

        void fillgrid(string s = "Select * from Sheet1")
        {
            cmd1.CommandText = s;
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd1;
            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds, "T1");
            dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("datasource", ds, "T1");
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     
            SqlDataAdapter DX = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  Drug AS [نام دارو], food AS غذا, Lactation AS شیردهی, Pregnancy AS بارداری FROM  [Sheet1] WHERE Drug LIKE'" + textBox1.Text + "%'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DX.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;      
        }
    }
}
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure that there is a local db on the other PC, because in your connection string you've set the data source to a local database

Comment: As @Ben mentioned make sure that the instance you referencing in your connection string exists in the host.

Comment: Try creating LocalDB instance in cmd such like `sqllocaldb c MSSQLLocalDB 11.0`. In your connection string try change data source to `(LocalDb)\v11.0` & use `|DataDirectory|` instead of `Application.StartupPath`.